# Contructing for loop on a dataframe R

Tags: r, for-loop

I don't understand how to corectly construct a **for loop**.
I have testes the code for one row (row 10508, cause it has two outliers), and it works.

```
test <- apply(Data, 1, outliers_fun)

if(length(outliers_fun(Data[10508,]))>0) {
    yB <- which(as.numeric(Data[10508,]) == as.numeric(unlist(test[10508])), arr.ind=TRUE) 
    m <- as.matrix(yB[10508])
  }
  addStyle(wb, sheet="df", style = red_style,  cols=m, rows=10508+1)
```

So I'm trying to put this into for loop to to the outlier search on the whole dataframe.
Here's what I tried:

```
i <- 0 #is this necessary?
 
for(i in nrow(Data)){
  if(length(outliers_fun(Data[i,]))>0) {
    yB[i] <- which(as.numeric(Data[i,]) == 
                  as.numeric(unlist(test[[i]])), arr.ind=TRUE) 
    m[i] <- as.matrix(yB[i])
  }
  addStyle(wb, sheet="df", style = red_style,  cols=m[i], rows=i+1)
}
```

How many brackets should be used? I tried **[i]** and **[[i]]**, but it's still not working for full dataframe like for the one row 10508.
Which brackets shoul be used and what is wrong with the for loop?

Comment: Probably you meant `1:nrow(Data)`.

Comment: i <- 0 is not necessary. Also i usually starts with 1, because you want to start in the first row. there is no "zero" row